# AlertDialog query regarding DialogInterface.OnClickListener - Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am populating my AlertDialog with entries from a SharedPreferences file.

There are 8 entries. In the SharePreferences file they were entered as ("serverurl", London, UK).

The AlertDialog displays the values (London, UK etc.) in alphabetical order, which is what I want.

When an option is clicked I use the code below:

```
new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface,
                int i) {;
                setServer(i);   
            }
        })
```

This is where my problem lies. I don't want to pass the integer based on position of the option chosen, I want it to pass the key for that value.

For example if a user clicks Washington, DC at position 4 I don't want to use "4" as the parameter, I want it to pass the key (in this example it will be a URL/IP address).

In short is this possible? Or are options in a shared-preferences only accessible using the position they appear?

Comment: Hi casey, thanks for the tip, I often forget to accept due to a mixture of being too busy and still having trouble with the same question. I'll get into the habit of accpeting even if it hasn't fully solved my issue.

Comment: Can't you just index into the SharedPreferences again to get the value of from the array?